# Hadoop what is it good for?

Tags: hadoop

I'm reading, reading and reading about this technology, and I still am not sure what it's good for.

1) It does not seem to support sequential jobs very well, most of the jobs out there are sequential in nature. - not saying it couldn't be made to work, but that getting it to work is very very clumsy.

2) Why can't this be done via load balanced services + 3rd party/custom no sql solution? NoSql solution eg. Azure Table or Federated Databases etc to provide the HDFS like feature, while the map reduce can be done inside a service. This will provide a better seperation of concern while providing much better access such as sequential read and what not. Yes cost could be an issue, but dang it if I had a petabyte or two of data to churn through $$$ is the least of my worries.

3) The other annoying thing is shipping the code over to run local on the file system. It's good for performance I get that, but horrible from a code organization / complexity management pov. Otherwise ORM wouldn't be so popular, since writting everything in UDF and Stored Procs are much much faster. I thought we took this route before and find out how much it sucked.

So just why is Hadoop so popular as clunky and slow as it is - I don't get it.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

How does where the code run affect code organization/management? It's transparent; that's the point.

Of course Hadoop's functionality could be recreated using an amalgam of a bunch of other technologies--M/R is a way, not a stack.

Job management is handled via a variety of apps.

You answered your own question regarding "3rd party/custom" solutions: the point is that it's a framework than can be used to eliminate most or all of the non-data-/app-specific development.

I've never been in an environment where "$$$ is the least of my worries", either.

It's unclear to me what your actual objections to it are.

Comment: Where the code is deployed matters. Let me ask you this. Why Soa? No DLL hell no jars no binaries to ship between teams. To most that's enough to make up for the hit in performance.

Comment: @Alwyn I have no idea what you're talking about--what binaries? What code "ships between teams? Hadoop moves the code around between nodes.

Comment: And the dependencies too? Like 3rd party library, runtime, VMS etc.

Comment: @Alwyn There are a number of ways to get dependencies distributed, including just putting then in HDFS. Don't know what VMs you're talking about. A runtime would have to exist on machines running your code whether it was Hadoop or other distributed solution--I don't see how any of these issues are unique to Hadoop, though.

Comment: @Dave thanks man your answer is fine. I get nosql, map reduce, and even hdfs. It's the idea of coupling code to persistence that I'm wrestling with. Especially deploying library into the persistence layer. It rarely was a good idea and I dunno if hadoop changes that